# How do I use Structr to iterate through elements in a cypher collection?

Tags: cypher, structr

I'm trying out Structr, which seems great, but I'm running into an issue where I want to loop through a returned collection and output an html element for each item in it. It's a little complicated by the fact that I also need to use merge_unique on the collection before I do so, because the old version of neo4j Structr uses chokes on a combination of optional match and collect(distinct n).

Here's the request I'm making in the cypher query pane of Structr:

```
MATCH (c:Country) WHERE c.code = 'US'
Optional match (c)<-[:THING_IN]-(t:Thing)-[:THING_BELONGS_TO]-(p:Project)
optional match (p)<-[:SPONSORS]-(sp)
where p.status = "ACTIVE"
with c, collect(distinct p) as projects, collect(sp.name) as sponsors
RETURN {
    name:c.name, 
    code:c.code, 
    open_projects:size(filter(x IN projects WHERE x.status = "ACTIVE")),
    closed_projects:size(filter(x IN projects WHERE x.status <> "ACTIVE")),
    all_projects:size(projects),
    sponsors:sponsors
}
```

So, "sponsors" is returned as a non-distinct collection of all the names of the sponsors of the projects. It works to then loop through the sponsors if they're returned as objects, and display ${sponsor.name} (after creating a data-binding with sponsor = merge_unique(data.sponsors), but I can't just display each sponsor from a collection of string variables.

I'm not sure I'm explaining this very well, but if you've used Structr, I expect this is a problem you've run into. If you can point me in the right direction, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the latest snapshot? Runs with Neo4j 3.0. I'll also post a reply below soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reproducing your query with the following test data, I get the same result (non-distinct list of sponsor names).

[image: Data]

If I add a `distinct` to the Cypher statement, it returns a distinct collection of the sponsors:

```
[...]
with c, collect(distinct p) as projects, collect(distinct(sp.name)) as sponsors
[...]
```

Note that the collection in `sponsors` is already a String array so you can't use a Structr repeater easily (there's a way but it's more complex).

To use Structr's data binding directly, modify the query to return objects (`sp.name` => `sp`) and create a nested repeater with a function query (in my example bound to the <b> element:

```
[...]
with c, collect(distinct p) as projects, collect(distinct(sp)) as sponsors
[...]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is what I did. I really like Structr. Any thoughts on when the next release is coming?

Comment: Probably around GraphConnect.